# Reference to range using embeded variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue with referring to multiple ranges using for loop.
I created a set of ranges using standardized names like range_[number].
Unfortunately when i try to refer to them I constantly get errors or empty ranges.

```
Sub add_new_country()

'count initial number of countries
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("countries_list"))
'name of last country
last_country = Range("countries_list").Cells(n).Value

range_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells
range_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Operations").Columns(2).Cells

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 2
    Set active_range = Range("range_" & i)
    For Each c In active_range
        If c.Value = last_country Then
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            c.EntireRow.Cells.Copy
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            c.Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        End If
    Next c
Next i

End Sub
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: are you using `Named Range` ? or you are trying to refere to `range_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It would help others answer you if you included the data and the exact error messages you get.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance about asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't refer like you're trying to do

better use an array of ranges

```
Dim ranges(1 To 2) As Range
Set ranges(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells
Set ranges(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Operations").Columns(2).Cells

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 2
    Set active_range = ranges(i)
```

Comment: I was going to press enter with the exact same code, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @ShaiRado, this time!